# Campo quantidade no carrinho nao aparece valor - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Sou bem iniciante em PHP e estou no final do projeto.
Porem estou usando o tema Sidney com woocommerce, apesar do alerta de incompatibilidade.
No campo quantidade, onde o comprador aumenta ou diminui os valores para acrescentar ao carrinho, o valor incrementado nao aparece.
Ja pesquisei algumas coisas achei que aqui teria uma ajuda mais rápida.

Segue o print.
[image: Bug]

Eu nao tenho como mudar o tema infelizmente.
Pensei em esconder esse campo pra que o usuário clique em comprar e a cada clique, o carrinho vai incrementando um. Isso funciona pois quando clico no botão de compra, ele adiciona um produto e isso seria a solução gambiarra pra mim no momento.
Não posso deixar um único produto por pedido pois o cliente tem que poder comprar mais de um ingresso no pedido.
Em outros temas que tenho, o campo quantidade funciona bem, somente com esse tema que nao consegui.

Answer (score 0):

so pra avisar, obtive ajuda de um amigo e a solucao foi acertar 
O arquivo CSS em /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css

Editar a parte

. woocommerce .quantity .qty

Resolvido

Answer (score -1):

Editar o arquivo CSS em /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css

Procure por:

. woocommerce .quantity .qty

Edita a parte do tamanho:

```
{
  width:3,61em;
  text-align:center
}
```

para:

```
{
  width:8em;
  text-align:center
}
```